# How to update the child job status to the parent

Tags: jenkins

I have a seed job which runs a DSL and in turn run many child jobs.
How can a child job status failure/success be updated to the seed job.

Comment: Hi. Which DSL? Might help us to help you..

Comment: At the end of each Build the child job has to report the outcome of the build to the parent job. Its a Jenkins DSL

Comment: Hi. Which DSL? Might help us to help you..

Comment: There are numerous DSL's that run correspondingly example: Ansible, Docker, Database, Elasticsearch, Java, Web etc